# Convert jQuery Mobile radios from horizontal to vertical

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to convert jQuery mobile radios to vertically stacked ones dynamically. I have this.

```
$('fieldset').data('type', 'vertical').controlgroup('refresh');
```

Should this not change all the data-type="horizontal" to data-type="vertical"? Even when I inspect it I see no change. I've also played with trigger('create') on the form and this just messes up the radios.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" class="required" checked />
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" class="required" />
        <label for="female">Female</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally use to change the styles applied to the controlgroup and radio buttons whenever I need to change from horizontal to vertical or vice versa. Following is the code, hope this fits into your requirement.

```
$("fieldset").attr('data-type','vertical').removeClass('ui-controlgroup-horizontal').addClass('ui-controlgroup-vertical');

var $firstLbl =  $("fieldset").find('div.ui-radio:first').children('label'),
    $secondLbl = $("fieldset").find('div.ui-radio:last').children('label');

    $firstLbl.removeClass('ui-corner-left').addClass('ui-corner-top');
    $firstLbl.children('span').removeClass('ui-corner-left').addClass('ui-corner-top');
    $secondLbl.removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('ui-corner-bottom');
    $secondLbl.children('span').removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('ui-corner-bottom');

    //show the radio buttons.
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(i) {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.next().addClass('ui-btn-icon-left').find('span.ui-btn-text').after($('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-radio-off">&nbsp;</span>'));
    });

    //Set the first one as checked by default.
    $("input[type='radio']:first").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: It is ether this solution or dynamically recreating whole filedset from scratch.

Comment: Would be great if this functionality was part of jQM so you could just do it in a single line.